# how should i oranize the code in a simple way

Tags: excel, vba

'How can i simplify this code please. For me its working, but with small changes i have to change every box, and is confusing like this. Is there a way to simplify. Thanks in advance***

I have not so much experience with coding, please if you have an answer be not so technical. '
For me it would be easier if i made small changes, all the textboxes should be affected with the change. How it is now, like you see, i have to make changes in every textbox

```
    Private Sub ComboBox1_change()
On Error Resume Next
Dim x As Double
x = 100
Me.TextBox9 = (Val(Me.TextBox5) + Val(Me.TextBox6)) / 100 * Me.ComboBox3


Me.TextBox6 = Val(Me.TextBox5) * Val(Me.TextBox4) / x
Me.TextBox7 = Val(Me.TextBox5) + Val(Me.TextBox6) + Val(Me.TextBox9)
'Me.TextBox7 = Val(Me.TextBox5) + Val(Me.TextBox6)

If Me.ComboBox1.Value = "gr" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "gr" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3)

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "kg" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "kg" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3)

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Liter" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "Liter" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3)
ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "kg" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "Gr" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3) / 1000

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Liter" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "dl" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3) / 10

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Liter" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "cl" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3) / 100


ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Pak" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "Pak" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3)

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Bussel" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "Bussel" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3)
End If
        End Sub
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
On Error Resume Next
Dim x As Double

x = 100
Me.TextBox9 = (Val(Me.TextBox5) + Val(Me.TextBox6)) / 100 * Me.ComboBox3
Me.TextBox6 = Val(Me.TextBox5) * Val(Me.TextBox4) / x
Me.TextBox7 = Val(Me.TextBox5) + Val(Me.TextBox6) + Val(Me.TextBox9)
'Me.TextBox7 = Val(Me.TextBox5) + Val(Me.TextBox6)


If Me.ComboBox1.Value = "gr" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "gr" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3)

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "kg" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "kg" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3)

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Liter" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "Liter" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3)
ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "kg" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "Gr" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3) / 1000

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Liter" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "dl" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3) / 10

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Liter" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "cl" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3) / 100

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Pak" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "Pak" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3)

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Bussel" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "Bussel" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3)
End If
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox3_change()
On Error Resume Next
Dim x As Double

x = 100
Me.TextBox9 = (Val(Me.TextBox5) + Val(Me.TextBox6)) / 100 * Me.ComboBox3
Me.TextBox6 = Val(Me.TextBox5) * Val(Me.TextBox4) / x
Me.TextBox7 = Val(Me.TextBox5) + Val(Me.TextBox6) + Val(Me.TextBox9)
'Me.TextBox7 = Val(Me.TextBox5) + Val(Me.TextBox6)


If Me.ComboBox1.Value = "gr" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "gr" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3)

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "kg" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "kg" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3)

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Liter" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "Liter" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3)
ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "kg" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "Gr" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3) / 1000

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Liter" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "dl" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3) / 10

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Liter" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "cl" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3) / 100

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Pak" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "Pak" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3)

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Bussel" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "Bussel" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3)
End If


End Sub

  


Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
For x = 0 To ListBox1.ListIndex

TextBox1.Value = ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 1)
TextBox2.Value = ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 2)
ComboBox1.Value = ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 3)
TextBox4.Value = ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 4)
Next
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_change()
On Error Resume Next
Dim x As Double

x = 100
Me.TextBox9 = (Val(Me.TextBox5) + Val(Me.TextBox6)) / 100 * Me.ComboBox3

Me.TextBox6 = Val(Me.TextBox5) * Val(Me.TextBox4) / x
Me.TextBox7 = Val(Me.TextBox5) + Val(Me.TextBox6) + Val(Me.TextBox9)
'Me.TextBox7 = Val(Me.TextBox5) + Val(Me.TextBox6)

If Me.ComboBox1.Value = "gr" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "gr" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3)

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "kg" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "kg" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3)

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Liter" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "Liter" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3)
ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "kg" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "Gr" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3) / 1000

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Liter" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "dl" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3) / 10

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Liter" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "cl" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3) / 100

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Pak" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "Pak" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3)

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Bussel" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "Bussel" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3)
End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox3_change()
On Error Resume Next
Dim x As Double

x = 100
Me.TextBox9 = (Val(Me.TextBox5) + Val(Me.TextBox6)) / 100 * Me.ComboBox3

Me.TextBox6 = Val(Me.TextBox5) * Val(Me.TextBox4) / x
Me.TextBox7 = Val(Me.TextBox5) + Val(Me.TextBox6) + Val(Me.TextBox9)
'Me.TextBox7 = Val(Me.TextBox5) + Val(Me.TextBox6)


If Me.ComboBox1.Value = "gr" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "gr" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3)

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "kg" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "kg" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3)

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Liter" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "Liter" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3)
ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "kg" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "Gr" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3) / 1000

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Liter" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "dl" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3) / 10

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Liter" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "cl" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3) / 100

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Pak" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "Pak" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3)

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Bussel" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "Bussel" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3)
End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox4_afterupdate()
On Error Resume Next
Dim x As Double

x = 100
Me.TextBox9 = (Val(Me.TextBox5) + Val(Me.TextBox6)) / 100 * Me.ComboBox3
Me.TextBox6 = Val(Me.TextBox5) * Val(Me.TextBox4) / x
Me.TextBox7 = Val(Me.TextBox5) + Val(Me.TextBox6) + Val(Me.TextBox9)
'Me.TextBox7 = Val(Me.TextBox5) + Val(Me.TextBox6)


If Me.ComboBox1.Value = "gr" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "gr" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3)

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "kg" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "kg" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3)

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Liter" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "Liter" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3)
ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "kg" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "Gr" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3) / 1000

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Liter" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "dl" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3) / 10

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Liter" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "cl" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3) / 100

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Pak" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "Pak" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3)

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Bussel" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "Bussel" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3)
End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox5_afterupdate()
On Error Resume Next
Dim x As Double

x = 100
Me.TextBox9 = (Val(Me.TextBox5) + Val(Me.TextBox6)) / 100 * Me.ComboBox3
Me.TextBox6 = Val(Me.TextBox5) * Val(Me.TextBox4) / x
Me.TextBox7 = Val(Me.TextBox5) + Val(Me.TextBox6) + Val(Me.TextBox9)
'Me.TextBox7 = Val(Me.TextBox5) + Val(Me.TextBox6)


If Me.ComboBox1.Value = "gr" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "gr" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3)

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "kg" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "kg" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3)

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Liter" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "Liter" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3)
ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "kg" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "Gr" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3) / 1000

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Liter" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "dl" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3) / 10

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Liter" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "cl" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3) / 100

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Pak" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "Pak" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3)

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Bussel" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "Bussel" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3)
End If

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox6_change()
On Error Resume Next
Dim x As Double

x = 100
Me.TextBox9 = (Val(Me.TextBox5) + Val(Me.TextBox6)) / 100 * Me.ComboBox3
Me.TextBox6 = Val(Me.TextBox5) * Val(Me.TextBox4) / x
Me.TextBox7 = Val(Me.TextBox5) + Val(Me.TextBox6) + Val(Me.TextBox9)
'Me.TextBox7 = Val(Me.TextBox5) + Val(Me.TextBox6)


If Me.ComboBox1.Value = "gr" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "gr" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3)

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "kg" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "kg" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3)

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Liter" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "Liter" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3)
ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "kg" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "Gr" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3) / 1000

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Liter" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "dl" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3) / 10

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Liter" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "cl" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3) / 100

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Pak" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "Pak" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3)

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Bussel" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "Bussel" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3)
End If

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox7_afterupdate()
On Error Resume Next
Dim x As Double

x = 100
Me.TextBox9 = (Val(Me.TextBox5) + Val(Me.TextBox6)) / 100 * Me.ComboBox3

Me.TextBox6 = Val(Me.TextBox5) * Val(Me.TextBox4) / x
Me.TextBox7 = Val(Me.TextBox5) + Val(Me.TextBox6) + Val(Me.TextBox9)
'Me.TextBox7 = Val(Me.TextBox5) + Val(Me.TextBox6)


If Me.ComboBox1.Value = "gr" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "gr" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3)

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "kg" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "kg" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3)

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Liter" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "Liter" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3)
ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "kg" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "Gr" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3) / 1000

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Liter" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "dl" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3) / 10

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Liter" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "cl" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3) / 100

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Pak" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "Pak" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3)

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Bussel" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "Bussel" Then
Me.TextBox5 = Val(Me.TextBox2) * Val(Me.TextBox3)
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow that's alot. Look into using a  collection or a dictionary or an array. Those are usually the way to go instead of creating a separate variable for each

Comment: Thanks Josh for your direction, but like I said, it took me a while to get this code to work like I want, but there must me a better way. Your suggestion to look into collections or dictionary, is like chinese for me. Help me out with this one, what to search on google, how to search?

Comment: Profex gives a great answer. Tbh I don't use forms often. But down the road to take your skills to a next level. Google excel mastery dictionaries or collections or arrays. There's a bald british guy that runs that website, and does a really amazing job of explaining the concepts. Best of luck!

Comment: Sorry, but as worded the question is not focused enough for Stack Overflow. You could take a look at [what kind of posts are on topic for a companion site, Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), it may be on topic there, provided you explain what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: @Erol: closing questions that are off topic is entirely normal, this site is moderated and curated. Sorry, you can't ask people to 'leave your question be'.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just throw everything into an update function and call an update function from each control.  That way the values are always calculated the same, without the duplication.

On another note, why are some *Textboxes* using `_Change` and other using `_Afterupdate`?
I cleaned up the code a bit, by checking if `TextBox5` & `TextBox6` were the same.
Also, the `For` loop in the *ListBox* was not necessary.  I also added a check to make sure the index was valid.

> **Edit:** There is a number of ways you can deal with it, but basically you need a flag to tell you not to update.  Usually you would turn off  `Application.EnableEvents`, but apparently that's only for the Excel events, not custom form events. This could be a global/module level variable, or as I updated it a `Static` variable (As I was typing this answer, I realize that you probably want to use a global/module variable because of the `Listbox`, I'll leave it for you to change).
> I also updated it so that you could put it in a `Module` by adding a parameter for the `Userform`.

> I highly recommend reading [UserForm1.Show](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/) on how to use forms properly.  It's well worth the read.  99% of VBA programmers do it they way you did (which is fine).  For years I did it the normal way, still do for most forms; But I hated using `Globals`, didn't like passing values from the `Form` to a `Function`, because there was always too many parameters for my like...there was just no good way to pass data between the `Form` and the `Module/Class` that that it belonged to.

```
Private Sub UpdateForm(Form As UserForm)
Static Updating As Boolean
Dim x As Double
    If Updating Then Exit Sub
    Updating = True
    On Error Resume Next
    x = 100
    With Form
        .TextBox9 = (Val(.TextBox5) + Val(.TextBox6)) / 100 * .ComboBox3
        .TextBox6 = Val(.TextBox5) * Val(.TextBox4) / x
        .TextBox7 = Val(.TextBox5) + Val(.TextBox6) + Val(.TextBox9)
        '.TextBox7 = Val(.TextBox5) + Val(.TextBox6)
        If .ComboBox1.Value = .ComboBox2.Value Then
            .TextBox5 = Val(.TextBox2) * Val(.TextBox3)
        ElseIf .ComboBox1.Value = "kg" And .ComboBox2.Value = "Gr" Then
            .TextBox5 = Val(.TextBox2) * Val(.TextBox3) / 1000
        ElseIf .ComboBox1.Value = "Liter" And .ComboBox2.Value = "dl" Then
            .TextBox5 = Val(.TextBox2) * Val(.TextBox3) / 10
        ElseIf .ComboBox1.Value = "Liter" And .ComboBox2.Value = "cl" Then
            .TextBox5 = Val(.TextBox2) * Val(.TextBox3) / 100
        End If
    End With
    Updating = False
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_change()
    UpdateForm Me
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
    UpdateForm Me
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox3_change()
    UpdateForm Me
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
    If ListBox1.ListIndex >= 0 Then
        TextBox1.Value = ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 1)
        TextBox2.Value = ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 2)
        ComboBox1.Value = ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 3)
        TextBox4.Value = ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 4)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_change()
    UpdateForm Me
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox3_change()
    UpdateForm Me
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox4_afterupdate()
    UpdateForm Me
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox5_afterupdate()
    UpdateForm Me
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox6_change()
    UpdateForm Me
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox7_afterupdate()
    UpdateForm Me
End Sub
```

***Bonus:** If you really want to create some nice form code, check out [Model, View, ViewModel](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2020/09/13/model-view-viewmodel/).
It might be a bit over your head, but it's a great resource on some nice concepts that don't get used in VBA much.*

Comment: omg, i was doing almost the same as profex his answer, but had put the code in a module. :)) and tried to call it from there. Thank you so much profex for your great solution. With the change and update textboxes, I really don't know why, was messing arround. Is working for me like this so i kept it. I think when 'Total' is in _change the rest of the textboxes would'nt update. Thanks again for your answer profex, This really made it easier for me.

Comment: Everything works fine, but now i have a 'out of stack' error. I've searched it up and it seems there is too much events going on with the 'call function'. How can i correct this please !

Comment: Thank you profex, I had tried Application.EnableEvents = True and false, but the userform had a hard time. Even crashed sometimes. With your update, it works smooth and like i planned to do. Thank you very much. From Today we are again in a lockdown till 13 dec. All restaurants and hotels must close; So i hope to finish this project. There is a long way to finish this. Like: filtering recipes.. Main dish, Entree etc etc. Reports, avarage, incoming stock ...  I will figure it out for sure.  I got so far with 0 knowledge, i can read and understand the codes, but need sometimes help. Thanks again